# play-services-auth dependency in React Native with react-native-google-signin

Tags: android, gradle, google-api, react-native, google-authentication

I've followed all of the steps in the instructions at https://github.com/apptailor/react-native-google-signin to get this setup with the Android environment (no issues in iOS) in React Native, but am getting the following error when running `react-native run-android`

```
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-google-signin'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':react-native-google-signin:_debugCompile'.
  > Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0.
    Searched in the following locations:
        file:/Users/steven/.m2/repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/8.3.0/play-services-auth-8.3.0.pom
        file:/Users/steven/.m2/repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/8.3.0/play-services-auth-8.3.0.jar
        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/8.3.0/play-services-auth-8.3.0.pom
        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/8.3.0/play-services-auth-8.3.0.jar
        file:/usr/local/opt/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/8.3.0/play-services-auth-8.3.0.pom
        file:/usr/local/opt/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/8.3.0/play-services-auth-8.3.0.jar
    Required by:
        PowerToolSafe:react-native-google-signin:unspecified
```

I've added the following to the top-level build.gradle:

```
'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0'
```

And the following to the app-level build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
...
dependencies {
    ...
    compile project(":react-native-google-signin")
}
```

I've tried different versions of google-services but end up still getting the build error. In JCenter I don't even see `com.google.android.gms.play-services-auth`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Fixed this by adding `Google Repository` and `Google Play services` from the Android SDK Manager. It failed the first build, but completed thereafter for whatever reason.

[image: Android SDK Manager]

Comment: I had the same issue with https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob and the solution is the same